# .NET 7 attribute route not working with some values

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-7.0

I am trying to do routing with attribute route.
There are nearly 20 pages in my project and the route does not work on one of the pages.
When I define the route as below, it does not redirect to the page.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   [Route("/blog")]
   public IActionResult BlogsPage()
   {
       return View();
   } 
}
```

Instead, when I change my route definition, the page opens properly.

For example:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   [Route("/blogs")]
   public IActionResult BlogsPage()
   {
       return View();
   } 
}
```

or

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   [Route("/blog2")]
   public IActionResult BlogsPage()
   {
       return View();
   } 
}
```

In this way, when "blogs" is defined as "blog2", the page opens, but it does not open with the "blog" definition.

How can I fix this?

Route related configurations in `Program.cs`

```
using System.Globalization;
using DLL.CoreItems; 
using FrontWeb.Filters;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;
using PO.Base.Interface;
using Utility.CacheMechanism;
using Utility.SessionAndCookieHelper;
using WebBase.Helper_Codes.Navigator;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args); 

builder.Services.AddDetection();

builder.Services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
});

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddScoped(x => x
    .GetRequiredService<IUrlHelperFactory>()
    .GetUrlHelper(x.GetRequiredService<IActionContextAccessor>().ActionContext));

builder.Services.AddSession();
builder.Services.AddOptions();
builder.Services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

builder.Services.AddMvc(options => { }).AddViewLocalization().AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
builder.Services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
{
    options.EnableForHttps = true;
    options.MimeTypes = new[] { "text/plain" };
    options.MimeTypes = new[] { "text/css" };
    options.MimeTypes = new[] { "application/javascript" };
    options.MimeTypes = new[] { "text/html" };
    options.MimeTypes = new[] { "application/xml" };
    options.MimeTypes = new[] { "text/xml" };
    options.MimeTypes = new[] { "application/json" };
    options.MimeTypes = new[] { "text/json" };
});
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ModelContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("cs")));
builder.Services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new ErrorHandlingFilter());
});

builder.Services.AddResponseCaching();

var supportedCultures = new[]
{
    new CultureInfo("tr-TR")
};

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions()
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestCulture("tr-TR"),
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
});
using (var serviceScope = app.Services.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
{
    var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ModelContext>();
    context.Database.EnsureCreated();
}
app.UseResponseCompression();
app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandler>(); 
app.UseHsts();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
    {
        const int durationInSeconds = 365 * 60 * 60 * 24;
        ctx.Context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] =
            "public,max-age=" + durationInSeconds;
    }
});
app.UseCookiePolicy();
app.UseSession(); 

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"); 



app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");

    await next();
});
app.UseResponseCaching();
UrlHelperResolver.Configure(app.Services.GetRequiredService<IUrlHelperFactory>());
ContextHelper.Configure(app.Services.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>());

app.Run();
```

I tried to get different results by changing the configurations in `Program.cs` but i didn't succeed.

> The strange thing is that I can publish and run at localhost:5000 and navigate to the "/blog" page. There seems to be a problem with debugging

Comment: Can you please add a [mre] including attempted urls?

Comment: Do you have any other configuration in program.cs file which has not been shared?

Comment: I completely agree.  Without seeing more configuration details in the Program.cs, it is more guessing that actually providing a good answer.

Comment: I couldn't find a solution for the problem. I'm continuing on a different computer, here is no problem for now. Thanks

Comment: You could try the way I provided, I hope that would resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to do routing with attribute route. When I define the
> route in this way, it does not redirect to the page.

Well, based on your scenario and description its not clear how did you you tried to reach your route and its the crucial point. Accordingly to your program.cs configuration your default route has been set to `{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}` also index is missing within your controller, and as per the [attribute route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#attribute-route-order) defination index will be invocked by default. Consequently, it should return to 404 error.

[image]

> In this way, when "blogs" is defined as "blog2", the page opens, but
> it does not open with the "blog" definition.

Its not quite evident, why didn't you able to reach the route endpoint. I have tried in my local test and can hit the endpoint from browser, as you can see below:

[image]

> How can I fix this?

Before moving to solution, let me explain you something, If you check the  [Route("")] interface which is the type of [RouteAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.routeattribute?view=aspnetcore-7.0) derived from [IRouteTemplateProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.routing.iroutetemplateprovider?view=aspnetcore-7.0) that has [Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.routeattribute.template?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-routeattribute-template) and [Name property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.routeattribute.name?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-routeattribute-name) as you can see below:

[image]

Thus, if you want to redirect to the route from another controller action you should call it by the route name, not template name which is missing in your code and you have used [Route("/blog")] which is template name.

**Solution:**

In order to resolve your issue, you should use route name besides, route template. You can do that as following:

```
        [Route("blog", Name = "blog")]
        public IActionResult BlogsPage()

        {
            return View();
        }
```

**Note:** First one is route template and the next one is route name, when calling from another controller action, you should use route name according to your scenario.

On top of this, from the action of another controller where you want to redirect to your blog action, you can all it like below:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return RedirectToRoute("blog");
        }
```

Output:

[image]

In addition, if you want to load your blog action at the beginning, you should configure your default route pattern.

**Note:** Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#combining-attribute-routes) for [more details about attribute routing.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#combining-attribute-routes)

Comment: I couldn't understand what the problem was. It works on a different computer, it works after I get publish, when I type "/blog/", "/blogs", "/blog2" instead of "/blog" it works, I opened it in a different browser and it works there. Sorry, I don't have any data to transfer.

Comment: In my test its has been also worked as expected and not clear why its not working within your machine, however, for redirecting from another controller action to your blog action, you can use, route name instead of route template, you can follow the steps provided.